# Data manipulation in python for an excel file

Tags: python, pandas, panel-data

I have to conduct a panel analysis for Euro area countries. I have an excel dataset for all the 20 countries in the Euro Area for the years starting from 1995 to 2022 for the HCPI, the final aggregate demand, the real GDP. My aim is to identify the drivers behind the current inflation and in order to do so I have to index all my variables for 2005 as base year and then calculate growth rates. My question is: how can I do it in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very ambiguous about one of the most important things when processing data, its format.
If it's an Excel file then you can export it as a CSV file. You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) that CSV file and manipulate it as a DataFrame object.

From your description I am assuming the file in question looks something like this:

| YEAR | COUNTRY | HCPI | FAD | GDP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1997 | France | x | y | z |
| ... | ..... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2005 | France | w | u | v |

Then after `pandas.read_csv()`' ing into a data dataframe (let's call it df) you can use something like `df[df['YEAR'] >= 2005 ]` to **return all** the *rows* starting from the year 2005 ([See more](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Nyandwi/machine_learning_complete/blob/main/2_data_manipulation_with_pandas/2_data_manipulation_with_pandas.ipynb#scrollTo=RCc2oXwszDDB)).

Assuming the formula for the growth rate is:

rgdp_growth_rate = (current_year_rgdp - last_year_rgdp) / the last_year_rgdp

which in python would be something like:

```
df["RGDP_GROWTH_RATE"] = (df["GDP"].diff() / df['GDP'].shift(periods=1))*100
```

What we are doing here:

- `df["RGDP_GROWTH_RATE"] =`: In pandas you add new columns by simply defining with a key like `df['NEW_COLUMN'] = something`
- `df["GDP"].diff()`: the "(current_year_rgdp - last_year_rgdp)" part of the equation.
- `df['GDP'].shift(periods=1)`: This shifts the GDP column so we can divide by last year's GDP.

See [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Nyandwi/machine_learning_complete/blob/main/2_data_manipulation_with_pandas/2_data_manipulation_with_pandas.ipynb) for a tutorial on how to manipulate dataframes using the Pandas library.